# How do I pass url parameters within url parameters

Tags: url, parameters, parameter-passing

I want to show a pdf using google viewer like this:

https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf

But my page should be opened with parameters like this:

https://mywebsite.com/pdfgenerator.xhtml?parameter1=true&parameter2=false

(On this page a pdf is generated, and that is not a valid website)

That means that I should pass parameters within the url parameter of the first page, but then they get interpreted as the parameters for the first page.

https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://mywebsite.com/pdfgenerator.xhtml?parameter1=true&parameter2=false

How do I solve this problem? How do I pass a parameter within a parameter? I can't find any information about it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved: If you encode it using encodeURIComponent and then pass it as the parameter it works. If you need to do it quickly you can use [this TryIt from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuricomponent). Adjust the address, click run and click the button, then copy the link.